# Can I build a wall directly underneath a steel basement beam?

Tags: basement

I'm framing an interior wall in my basement. There is a load bearing steel beam that runs length of the home. Can I build my wall to run parallel underneath the beam about 16 feet and secure it?

Comment: When you add the wall, try not to make the new wall's studs so long that you have to bash them into position with a framing hammer.  Doing so makes them transfer load from the beam to the floor slab, and it might not be intended to accept that load (depends on how much the beam is carrying.)  You might want to Google for *floating wall* although you don't have to build exactly that; just don't make those studs too snug.

Comment: @JeffWheeler +1 for recognizing the steel beam can deflect putting a load on the slab by transferring the load through the studs to the slab.

Comment: "and secure it?" +1. IDK what type of beam clamp to use here; this just shows nails (and destructive methods) : [How can I attach a 2x4 wall frame to the underside of a steel I-beam.](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/62496/attaching-non-load-bearing-walls-to-steel-i-beams)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's quite normal. Since the beam bears the load, it's a simple non-bearing wall.