# How attach a framing wood to construction beam

Tags: framing, construction, beam, nailing

my first framing project ever for my basement

I want to build a wall along a construction beam

I am reading on google that I should not make any holes in the beam and I saw this video on nailing against the beam

https://youtu.be/wN7ftczQfok?t=1758

I wonder if I should or should not nail a frame against the beam and what is the right way to do that

Note I only use normal 3 1/2 in nails and standard hammer no nail gun or anything

I have low budget

Comment: The only thing his nail does is hold it there until the liquid nails dries. W/o a pneumatic gun you can't do that. [Attaching non-load bearing walls to steel I-beams](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/62496/attaching-non-load-bearing-walls-to-steel-i-beams) "[with bent over nails]" is what I thought this was going to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I would use construction adhesive to glue the top plate to the beam.
You can hold it in place with clamps until the adhesive cures.
If your floor is concrete, I would also put down a layer of sill plate gasket foam to separate the bottom of the wall from the concrete. Concrete and wood don't get along.

If it were me, I'd build the wall in one piece next to the beam with a snug fit so you can just slide it into place. Apply the adhesive to both beam and top plate. Slide into place and use a level to check that it's plumb at both ends. Clamp to beam until adhesive sets.
Use a couple of concrete screws pre-drilled through the wood and into the floor to keep the bottom of the wall from moving sideways.